# Toast message keep being displayed on bottom of the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

I am trying to display a toast message on top of the screen but it keep showing on the bottom.

This the code I am using

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0)
toast.show()
```

I tried as well to change bkg and color but it seems difficult now even getView become deprecated

any idea who to force the toast on top of the screen ?

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is correct. Does anything happen if you let's say change (Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0) to (Gravity.TOP, 0, 250)

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65004242/toast-setgravity-does-not-work-in-my-avd-nexus-6-api-30

Comment: You can't set gravity since SDK 30, the default position is on the bottom and there is nothing we can do but using external libraries or build your own

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code its working just set gravity from TOP.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).apply {
 //If you want some margin from top to toast you can set yOffSet value
        setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 50)
        show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have tried and it's working fine.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

I moved to Snackbar instead of Toast message. It allow more easy customization